# Laravel blade extend within extend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have 2 different layout files I want to extend.

`app.blade.php` is the main layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>@yield('title') | {{ config('app.name') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('laraback/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('laraback/css/fontawesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('laraback/css/datatables.min.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

@yield('content')

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('laraback/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('laraback/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('laraback/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
@stack('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

`form.blade.php` is a child layout I want to use:

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my form code:

```
@section('content')
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" novalidate>
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="form-check-input">
                Remember
            </label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
    </form>
@endsection
```

I know I can use `@extends('layouts.app')` to get the form in the main layout, but how would I make it so that I can extend `form.blade.php` inside `app.blade.php`? (I know this sounds confusing).

This is an example of the result I want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>@yield('title') | {{ config('app.name') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('laraback/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('laraback/css/fontawesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('laraback/css/datatables.min.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" novalidate>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="form-check-input">
                                Remember
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('laraback/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('laraback/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('laraback/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
@stack('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In app.blade.php you can use @yield('content') like your code.
app.blade.php is perfect.

In your form.blade.php please fix like below.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    @include('form_content')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

And you need to make form_content.blade.php file with your form contents without @section and @endsection.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" novalidate>
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="form-check-input">
            Remember
        </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
</form>
```

Then you can see the result page as you want.

You can use @if to classify your @include clauses.
It means you can make a conditional clauses for every @include.
So if the condition is fit you can include one of among @include sections.

Comment: With this solution I'd have to create 2 different files just to display the same form.

Comment: What do you mean 2 different files?

Comment: I'd have to create seperate `form.blade.php` files for each form I want to use with the child layout, because the `@include` will be different each time.